# Fill <ul> with database values

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

how can I fill an unordered list with values from SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1? xD
I have this, using a asp:repeater:

```
<ul style="list-style:none">
    <asp:Repeater ID="deptList" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'
                NavigateUrl='<%# Link.ToDepartment(Eval("DepartmentID").ToString()) %>'
                />
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

and the output HTML:

```
<ul style="list-style:none">

            <li>
                <a href="http://...">value1</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="http://...">value2</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="http://...">value3</a>
            </li>

</ul>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a for loop to iterate all the values from the data source.
A sample:

```
<ul>
  <% foreach(var item in Collection) { %>
     <li><%=item.Property%></li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

And also you can use other data controls provided by ASP.NET, such as DataGrid.

And, if you insist using Repeater, I suggest you put `<ul>` in `HeaderTemplate`, `</ul>` into `FooterTemplate`, this prevents empty `<ul></ul>`.

Comment: And then use `myul.InnerHtml` right? So using a `for` loop iterating the DataTable and the InnerHtml property is faster (or better) than a `Repeater`? I dont like `DataGrids` because the `<table>` markup.

Comment: please see my update for the loop method. using the inline loop for its flexibility, slightly faster than Repeater.

Answer (score 2):

In your code behind you need to set the datasource for your repeater.

Something like:

```
deptList.DataSource = <your query result here>;
deptList.DataBind();
```